# Java OOP hierarchy - avoiding overhead

Tags: java, class, oop, hierarchy

I'm building a math library with coordinates / vectors.

There's a `ReadableCoord` and `WritableCoord` interfraces.

`AbstractCoordValue` can be extended to override the coordinate getters.

The problem is, the methods in immutable coord (AbstractCoordValue) can be implemented two ways, as seen here as *VARIANT 1* and *VARIANT 2*.

My DRY guts tell me to go with the first (then the impl is in one place only), but I'm not sure if the second doesn't have **less overhead**.

Which one to use?

```
public abstract class AbstractCoordValue implements ReadableCoord {

    // x(), y(), z() are abstract getters from the interface

    @Override
    public WritableCoord copy()
    {
        return new CoordVariable(x(), y(), z());
    }

    /* VARIANT 1 */
    @Override
    public WritableCoord add(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        return copy().add_ip(x(), y(), z()));
    }

    /* VARIANT 2 */
    @Override
    public WritableCoord add(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        return new CoordVariable(x()+x, y()+y, z()+z));
    }

    // --- snip ---
}
```

And the extending class, mutable:

```
public class CoordVariable extends AbstractCoordValue implements WritableCoord {

    private double x, y, z;

    // implements x(), y(), z() as getters

    public CoordVar(double x, double y, double x) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override // "_ip" stands for "in place"
    public WritableCoord add_ip(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        this.z += z;

        return this;
    }

    // --- snip ---
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to implement final class with immutable coordinates which implements `Readable` interface and another class with mutable coordinates which implements both `Readable` and `Writable` interfaces - i.e. to avoid using inheritance because extending immutable implementation with mutable violates [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (Liskov substitution) principle and contains potential vulnerability with treating mutable class like immutable.

Comment: Good point with that, but I want the mutable one to also have all the "do it in a copy" methods. Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: Not really, consider implementing `add` in slight other way - for your example, create immutable coords with sum, not create coords and then add something - i.e. variant 2. I also should let you know that I always prefer and recommend to use immutable classes/variables because they are thread-safe in most cases.

Comment: Actually you helped me enormously, now it's all pretty and easy to work with. Also, no more memory polluting with temporary Coords when chaining calls. Actually not strictly going by your advice, because ie. `add()` on `MutableCoord` returns itself, while `add()` on `ImmutableCoord` returns a new `MutableCoord` with the result. So when chaining calls, it automatically switches to mutables to save memory. (And it's with generics, so it's all in javadoc.. pretty cool I think. Maybe not 100% LSP but works good for me.)